# What is a single-prime function other than $f(x)=x!$?

Tags: number-theory, functions, prime-numbers

[Noob warning]: I am not a mathematician. If you use jargon, please explain or reference.

Other than $f(x)=x!$, what is a univariate non-piecewise function with a domain that is either all integers, or an infinite-sized subset of all integers, and whose range contains only integers and exactly one prime number?

For those that prefer lists, here are the criteria again:

- Univariate (one independent variable)
- Not $f(x)=x!$ (of which I 'think' meets the criteria below...)
- Non-piecewise (non-hybrid)
- Domain is either all integers or an infinite-sized subset of all integers
- Range contains only integers
- Range contains exactly one prime number

Comment: How is $x!$ bivariate?

Comment: $f(x)$ is univariate.

Comment: How do you feel about constant functions?

Comment: How about $f:\Bbb N\rightarrow\Bbb N$ given by $f(n)=p^n$ for $p$ a fixed prime.

Comment: Even more simply than most of those given: $f(x) = px$ (or $p\cdot(x+1)$, depending on how you feel about zero and where you want to start counting).  There are a bunch of problems with this question: (1) there are _many_ many such functions (in fact, $f(x) = p\cdot g(x)$ for any $g$ that's 1 somewhere and $\gt 1$ everywhere else - e.g., $g(x) = 1+(x-n)^2$ for any $n$ - also works); (2) 'non-piecewise' turns out to be a very artificial restriction to impose on functions; and (3) there's no motivation for this question - why do you want such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $f:\Bbb N\rightarrow\Bbb N$ given by $f(n)=p^n$ for $p$ a fixed prime.

Comment: Or $p^{n^2}$ if you want the domain to be all of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your example $f(x) = x!$ is $f_1$ in the following sequence of functions that meet your requirements (with $f_n(2) = 2$ being the only prime in the range of $f_n$):

$$f_n(x) = \frac{(x!)^n}{2^{n-1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=x^2+x$$
More generally, if $g(x)$ is any function with $f(1)=p$ is prime and $f(x) \geq 2$ for all $x$ then 
$$f(x)=xg(x)$$

Also
$$h(n)= lcm [1,2,3,..,n]$$

Also
$$u(n)=n^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$x^{x-1}$
for $x \ge 2$.

More generally,
for any prime $p$,
$x^{x-p+1}$
for $x \ge p$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(n)= (n-1) \cdot( n^2-1 \mod 4)$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x$ with a domain of "all composite integers together with 11".

$f(x)=7$

$f(x)=x^2-x$

Comment: this answer does not really explain the "jargon" in the question, please improve (this answer was flagged as being low quality and I was reviewing low quality posts)